# Does weak convergence in $L^{q}$ imply weak convergence in $L^{p}$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, lp-spaces, weak-convergence

Assume we have $u_{k} \rightharpoonup u$ in $L^{q}(\Omega)$, does it then follow that $u_{k} \rightharpoonup u$ in $L^{p}(\Omega)$, given that $q > p$ and $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is bounded?

I know strong convergence $u_{k} \rightarrow u$ in $L^{q}(\Omega)$ implies strong convergence $u_{k} \rightarrow u$ in $L^{p}(\Omega)$ given that $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is bounded. (using Jensen's Inequality to prove)

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since $\Omega$ is bounded, we have a continuous inclusion

$$j \colon L^q(\Omega) \hookrightarrow L^p(\Omega).$$

Now we have the general fact that a continuous linear map $T\colon X \to Y$ between two normed spaces (it holds more generally for Hausdorff locally convex spaces) is also continuous if we endow both spaces with their respective weak topology. Since a continuous map maps convergent sequences to convergent sequences, we have indeed the conclusion that weak convergence in $L^q(\Omega)$ implies weak convergence in $L^p(\Omega)$ for $\Omega$ of finite measure and $p \leqslant q$.

Comment: Thanks for your response. If you have a chance could you please look at [my post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1055665/convergence-of-truncation-in-lp).

Comment: Giuseppe Negro got there first. I'd have answered exactly the same (except for the formulation).

Comment: Would I be right in stating that the implication $T:X \rightarrow Y$ continuous implies $T:X \rightarrow Y$ sequentially continuous for any topology? but the reverse implication (sequential continuity of $T$ implies continuity of $T$) requires the space $X$ to be first countable?

Comment: The first part is true, continuity always implies sequential continuity. For the implication in the other direction, first countability of $X$ is a sufficient, but not a necessary condition. There are spaces that aren't first countable where nevertheless every sequentially continuous map is continuous. The spaces where sequential continuity implies continuity are called [sequential spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_space#Equivalent_conditions). But unless you're doing topology, it's a good rule of thumb that for a non-first countable space sequences probably don't suffice.

Comment: Daniel, I know that weak-to-weak sequentially continuous map is also norm-to-norm sequentially continuous. However, I think the opposite is not true.

Comment: @Svetoslav For the norm topologies, sequential continuity and continuity coincide. A neighbourhood subbasis of $0 \in Y$ in the weak topology is given by sets of the form $P(f) = \{ y : \lvert f(y)\rvert < 1\}$, where $f\in Y'$. Now $T^{-1}(P(f)) = \{ x : Tx \in P(f)\} = \{ x : \lvert f(Tx) \rvert < 1\} = P(f\circ T)$ is a weak neighbourhood of $0$ in $X$, hence $T$ is weakly continuous [at $0$, and as a linear map everywhere].

Comment: My apologies, Daniel. I didn't think before asking.