# Convergence of truncation in $L^{p}$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, lp-spaces

If you have a truncation $T_{k}u$ defined as:

$$
T_{k}u :=  \begin{cases} u,&  \text{ if }~ |u(x)| \leq 1\\ k\frac{u}{|u(x)|}, &   \text{ if }~|u(x)| > k  \end{cases} 
$$

If you consider the truncation of a function $u \in L^{p}(\Omega)$, $p > 1$ and $\Omega$ is bounded. Then how would you show that $T_{k}u \rightarrow u$ in $L^{p}(\Omega)$. It is clear that $T_{k}u \rightarrow u$ pointwise a.e. and by the Dominated convergence Theorem you could show that $T_{k}u \rightarrow u$ in $L^{1}(\Omega)$. I'm finding it hard to show convergence of truncation in $L^{p}(\Omega)$.

Does anyone have any idea how this can be shown?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Dominated Convergence Theorem works in $L^p$ spaces, too: if the dominating function is $L^p$ (with $1\le p < \infty$) then the convergence is in $L^p$ sense. To wit, assume that 
$$|f_n| \le g \in L^p,$$
with $p>1$ (the case $p=1$ being the DCT). Then the pointwise limit $f$ of $f_n$ (which exists by assumption) is dominated by $g$ and hence $f\in L^p$. Moreover, using the convexity inequality 
$$(a+b)^p\le 2^{p-1} (a^p+b^p), \qquad \forall a,b \ge 0$$
we see that 
$$
|f_n-f|^p\le C g^p, 
$$ and now the DCT gives convergence $f_n \to f$ in $L^p$ sense.

Comment: If you have a chance could you please look at [my post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1064764/verification-and-presentation-of-anisotropic-sobolev-space-results).

Comment: Hi, if you have a chance please look at a [proposed proof](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1072032/proposed-proof-for-convergence-in-sobolev-space) of mine where I try to implement the above.

Comment: Hi, could I ask your opinion on something. Do you think that [in the paper](http://caa.epfl.ch/publications/9-Boccardo-Dacorogna1984.pdf). On the second page of the paper it says "$V=W^{1,p}$, $p>1$ ($V' = W^{-1,p'})$ with $p' = \frac{p}{p-1}$". Do you think this is a typo? Shouldn't it be $V = W^{1,p}_{0}$. See the statement of the Theorem 1 at the bottom of the second page also. Thanks, sorry to bother.