# Proposed proof for convergence in Sobolev space

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing, sobolev-spaces, lp-spaces

Consider the Anisotropic Sobolev Space defined by:
$$W^{1,\overrightarrow{p},\epsilon}(\Omega) := \{ u \in L^{1+\frac{1}{\epsilon}}(\Omega), \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_{i}} \in L^{p_{i}}(\Omega), i=1,...,n \}$$
where $p_{i} > 1,~~ \forall i \in \{1,...,n\}$. Let $W^{1,\overrightarrow{p},\epsilon}_{0}(\Omega)$ be defined as the closure of $C^{\infty}_{c}(\Omega)$ in $W^{1,\overrightarrow{p},\epsilon}(\Omega)$ and let it be endowed with norm $\Vert u \Vert := \sum_{i=1}^{n}\Vert \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_{i}} \Vert$.

If you have a truncation $T_{k}u$ defined as:

$$
T_{k}u :=  \begin{cases} u(x),&  \text{ if }~ |u(x)| \leq 1\\ k\frac{u(x)}{|u(x)|}, &   \text{ if }~|u(x)| > k  \end{cases} 
$$

Prove that $T_{k}(u) \rightarrow u$ in $W^{1,\overrightarrow{p},\epsilon}_{0}(\Omega)$

**Proposed proof:**
Observe that $\frac{\partial T_{k}(u(x))}{\partial x_{i}} \rightarrow \frac{\partial u(x)}{\partial x_{i}}$ pointwise a.e.  and also $|\frac{\partial T_{k}(u(x))}{\partial x_{i}}| \leq |\frac{\partial u(x)}{\partial x_{i}}|$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Therefore by the Dominated Convergence Theorem it follows that for each $i \in \{1,...,n\}$ we have $\Vert \frac{\partial T_{k}u}{\partial x_{i}} - \frac{\partial u }{\partial x_{i}} \Vert_{L^{p_{i}}} \rightarrow 0$. Therefore $$T_{k}(u) \rightarrow u ~~~\text{in } W^{1,\overrightarrow{p},\epsilon}_{0}(\Omega)$$

$\square$

Is this a good proof? Are there any recommended changes?

Thanks.

Comment: You should give a better justification for the inequality $$\left\lvert \frac{\partial T_k u}{\partial x_i}\right\rvert\le \left\lvert\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}\right\rvert.$$This *is* true (up to a set of measure zero), but I am not so sure it is obvious.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Does this follow since $|\frac{\partial T_{k}u}{\partial x_{i}}| = |\frac{\partial u(x)}{\partial x_{i}}|$ or $|\frac{\partial T_{k}u}{\partial x_{i}}| = 0$ (depending on $u(x)$)?

Comment: @LucioD: Of course, but it is not clear that $T_ku$ is differentiable at almost all points.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Are you saying this is because it is not clear that $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_{i}}$ is differentiable at almost all points?

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro I meant "Are you saying this is because it is not clear that $u$ is differentiable at almost all points" in the above comment. Since if $u$ is differentiable I think differentiability of $T_{k}u$ follows easily, what do you think?

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Thanks for your response. How would you show that $T_{k}u$ is differentiable almost everywhere?

Comment: @JohnDoe: I know that the result is true, what I mean is that it was not properly justified. You need the Stampacchia's version of the chain rule (i.e. the one wisher mentions) to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be helpful to notice that if function $f$ is lipschitz and $f(0)=0$ then $f\circ u$ is sobolev with $\partial_i (f\circ u)(x)=f'(u)\partial_i u$.

Hence, you could use 
$$f(x):=
\begin{cases}
x & |x|<k\\
k & x>k\\
-k & x<-k
\end{cases} $$
as your truncation function. Of course $f$ satisfies all conditions I wrote above and of course the weak derivative is well defined, as you wrote in your post.

For your questions.

Q1: Yes.

Q2: This is the result of general chain rule. For prove details please refer to [Leoni](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821847686)'s book, exercise 10.37, for the idea of the proof, please refer to [E&G](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0849371570), Theorem 4.2.2

Q3: I think this question will be clear once you understand the proof of Theorem 4.2.2 above

Comment: I don't understand what exactly the problem is with the way I proved it? If we assume that $u \in W^{1,\overrightarrow{p},\epsilon}_{0}(\Omega)$ does it not follow that weak derivative is defined almost everywhere.

Comment: Well, the problem is, how can you make sure a combined function is weak differentiable?

Comment: Yeah I see that now, thought it followed easily, intuitively it does.

Comment: Yea, maybe check out the chain rule in Sobolev function is also helpful.

Comment: Hi I looked at your response. Could you please answer the following three questions when you have a chance:

1. Would the following be a sufficient justification to add to my proof: "Note that $T_{k}$ is a Lipschitz function and $T_{k}(0)=0$ then $T_{k}(u) \in W^{1,\overrightarrow{p},\epsilon}_{0}(\Omega)$ and so using the chain rule it follows that $\frac{\partial T_{k}}{\partial x_{i}} = \frac{\partial T_{k}}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_{i}}$", is that fine?

Comment: 2. Also, could I ask what the general result is for why firstly $T_{k}$ being a Lipschitz function and $T_{k}(0)=0$ implies $T_{k}(u) \in W^{1,\overrightarrow{p},\epsilon}_{0}(\Omega)$"?

Comment: 3. Why is it possible to use the chain rule where $T_{k}$ is Lipschitz continuous (so classically differentiable almost everywhere) and $u$ which is weakly differentiable?

Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: I updated my answer. Please check it out.

Comment: Hi I will check the details from the recommended books and links. This is off the topic but are you familiar with the following result for convergence of a sequence in a $L^{p}$ space: If $u_{n} \rightarrow u$ in $L^{p}(\Omega)$ then the sequence has a pointwise convergent subsequence $u_{n_{k}} \rightarrow u(x)$ a.e. Further, there exists an $h \in L^{p}(\Omega)$, where $h(x) \geq 0$ and $|u_{n_{k}}| \leq h(x)$ a.e. ? I vaguely remember this from somewhere but I'm not sure if it is valid.

Comment: The first one is try and the second one is LDCT

Comment: Does the LDCT not prove the converse, that if you have $u_{n_{k}} \rightarrow u(x)$ a.e. and $|u_{n_{k}}| \leq h(x)$ where $h \in L^{p}$ then $u_{n} \rightarrow u$ in $L^{p}$? This result I am asking about implies the existence of $h$. What do you think?

Comment: I think it is hold

Comment: Hi, could I ask your opinion on something. Do you think that [in the paper](http://caa.epfl.ch/publications/9-Boccardo-Dacorogna1984.pdf). On the second page of the paper it says "$V=W^{1,p}$, $p>1$ ($V' = W^{-1,p'})$ with $p' = \frac{p}{p-1}$". Do you think this is a typo? Shouldn't it be $V = W^{1,p}_{0}$. Thanks, sorry to bother.

Comment: We only use $W^{-1,p'}$ to denote the dual of $W_0^{1,p}$, without $0$, we usually use $(W^{-1,p'})^*$. So, it might be a typo

Comment: That's what I think also, thanks. But see the statement of theorem 1 at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Hi how you doing? Could I ask what page of the book you are referring to when you mention E&G Theorem 4.2.2 in your answer?

Comment: It is page 129 - 130

Comment: Oh okay, the product and chain rules. Thanks.

Comment: if $\Omega$ has finite measure then is it true that you do not need the requirement that $T_{k}(0) = 0$ according to exercise 10.37 in Leoni's book?

Comment: Yes you are correct

Comment: Hi sorry to bother, but I just want to confirm that for weak derivatives you don't require the  lower order derivatives to exist in order for the higher order derivatives to exist?