# Weak convergence in $L^q([0,1]) \subset L^p([0,1])$.

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, lp-spaces, weak-convergence

Suppose that $1 \leq p < q < \infty$ so that $L^q([0,1]) \subset L^p([0,1])$.

I want to show that for $f_n \in L^q([0,1])$, $f_n \to f$ weakly in $L^q \iff  f_n \to f$ weakly in $L^p$.

The forward direction is clear from the reverse-inclusion of the dual space (e.g. [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1055623/does-weak-convergence-in-lq-imply-weak-convergence-in-lp)).

I'd appreciate any help showing that the reverse direction is true.

Comment: What have you thought of ?

Comment: I suspect that the opposite arrow needs the extra assumption that $\|f_n\|_{L^q}\le C$ where $C$ is a constant that does not depend on $n$.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that $f_n\to f$ weakly in $\mathbb L^p$. We would like to find a condition which ensures that $f_n\to f$ weakly in $\mathbb L^q$. First of all, we should have that $f_n\in\mathbb L^q$, which is not automatic. Second, a weakly convergent sequence in a Banach space is bounded, hence we should also assume that $\sup_n\left\lVert f_n\right\rVert_q$ is finite, as Giuseppe Negro suggest.

So a not hopeless statement could be:

> Let $1\lt p<q\lt +\infty$ and let $\left(f_n\right)_{n\geqslant 1}$ be a sequence which converges weakly to $f$ in $\mathbb L^p$ and such that $\sup_n\left\lVert f_n\right\rVert_q<+\infty$. Then $f_n\to f$ in $\mathbb L^q$.

Under these assumptions, a subsequence $\left(f_{n_k}\right)_{k\geqslant 1}$ converges in $\mathbb L^q$ to some $g$. By the implication proved in the opening post, we have that $f_{n_k}\to g$ weakly in $\mathbb L^p$ hence $f=g$ and we deduce that $f\in\mathbb L^q$. For the moment, we have proven that a subsequence of $\left(f_n\right)_{n\geqslant 1}$ converges to $f$ weakly in $\mathbb L^q$. Nothing prevents us from applying to a subsequence of $\left(f_n\right)_{n\geqslant 1}$. Therefore, we get that for each subsequence of $\left(f_n\right)_{n\geqslant 1}$, we can extract a further subsequence which converges weakly to $f$ in $\mathbb L^q$.

Comment: Alternatively, we can recall that $f_n\rightharpoonup f$ in $L^p$ [resp. $L^q$] if and only if $\| f_n\|_p$ [resp. $\|f_n\|_q$] is uniformly bounded and $\int (f-f_n)\phi\, dx\to 0$ for all continuous $\phi$ (or any other dense subset of both spaces). So if a sequence converges weakly in one space the only missing assumption for convergence in the other space is a uniform bound on the norm.